# All of my community report links go to the same report

Tags: community, customer-community-plus

I have a community (with community plus licenses) that has a report detail page and a report list page. On the report list page I have several links to several different reports, but every link I click on brings me to the same report. I can define which report that is on the report detail page, but I can't figure out how to make allow different reports.

I've tried cloning that page or making another record detail page, that didn't work. I've tried making a normal page, but there doesn't seem to be a report component. I've tried making page variations, but those only seem assignable to audiences, whereas I need all the reports to be shared visible.

Edit: I have two reports I'm trying to surface. I can make each one visible one at a time, so I know they have all the permissions necessary to view the reports and the records and fields and all that. I just can't find a way to make both accessible at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my problem was that I was hard coding the report Id into the report detail page. I did this just so I could see it in the builder.

BUT what needs to be the case is to have the ID reference be `{!recordId}` , that way you can pass in whatever variable you need from links or from the report list view.